# Zend_Filter_StripTags ignoring allowed tags and attributes

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-filter-strip-tags

I'm trying to use the following code and it still strips out all the tags.  Am I doing something wrong?  I'm using the newest V1.10

```
$allowed_tags = array('img', 'object', 'param', 'embed', 'a', 'href', 'p', 'br', 'em', 'strong', 'li', 'ol', 'span');
$allowed_attributes = array('style', 'src', 'alt', 'href', 'width', 'height', 'value', 'name', 'type', 'embed', 'quality', 'pluginspage');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Filter_StripTags');
$html_filter = new Zend_Filter_StripTags($allowed_tags, $allowed_attributes);

$post = $html_filter->filter($this->_request->getPost('post'));
```

For a test case I've been using the same string, this is what's going in

```
<p><span style="background-color: #333399; color: #ff9900; text-decoration: underline;"><em><strong>This is a test</strong></em></span></p>

<p><span style="background-color: #333399; color: #ff9900;"><strong><em><sub><span style="background-color: #ffffff;"><span style="color: #000000;">asdf</span></span></sub></em></strong></span></p>

<p><span style="background-color: #333399; color: #ff9900;"><strong><em><span style="background-color: #ffffff;"><span style="color: #000000;"><sup>asdf</sup></span></span></em></strong></span></p>

<p><span style="background-color: #333399; color: #ff9900;"><strong><em><span style="background-color: #ffffff;"><span style="color: #000000;"><img title="Cool" src="../../../public/scripts/tinymce/plugins/emotions/img/smiley-cool.gif" border="0" alt="Cool" />asdf</span></span></em></strong></span></p>

<ul>

<li><span style="background-color: #333399; color: #ff9900;"><strong><em><span style="background-color: #ffffff;"><span style="color: #000000;">sadf</span></span></em></strong></span></li>

</ul>

<ol>

<li><span style="background-color: #333399; color: #ff9900;"><strong><em><span style="background-color: #ffffff;"><span style="color: #000000;">asdf</span></span></em></strong></span></li>

</ol>
```

This is what comes out

This is a test

asdf

asdf

asdf

sadf

asdf

---

Alternatively, perhaps there's something else wrong, as I just tried this:

```
$post = strip_tags($this->_request->getPost('elm1'), '<img><object><param><embed><a><href><p><br><em><strong><li><ol><span>');
```

And it stripped out everything as well.  Perhaps there is a setting in PHP that I'm missing?

Comment: The test string seems weird, but I'm testing out a WYSIWIG editor, so I used a bunch of the options and grabbed the html to use as a test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [API Doc for the StripTag Filter](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Filter/Zend_Filter_StripTags.html), the constructor signature is

```
void   __construct  ([string|array|Zend_Config $options = null])
```

So it should work with this (updated):

```
$html_filter = new Zend_Filter_StripTags(array(
  'allowTags' => $allowed_tags, 
  'allowAttribs' => $allowed_attributes
));
```

In earlier versions of Zend Framework (1.8.4) you had to do

```
$html_filter = new Zend_Filter_StripTags($allowed_tags, $allowed_attributes);
```

All versions should support:

```
$html_filter = new Zend_Filter_StripTags;
$html_filter->setAttributesAllowed($allowed_attributes);
$html_filter->setTagsAllowed($allowed_tags);
```

[Internally, StripTags works with str_replace and preg_replace](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Filter/StripTags.php). So even if someone added strip_tags() to the list of disallowed functions in your php.ini, the filter should work.

I've tried with your example code and it worked.

Comment: I had already tried your second way, I'll give the first a shot.

Comment: @Jhorra Can you be more specific about what happens when you do this? What is not working? Are you sure `$this->_request->getPost('post')` is a string?

Comment: See my post above, couldn't use the comment box as it wouldn't hold all the text

Comment: @Jhorra can you add the code to your question instead of to an answer please? Helps prevent clutter.

Comment: Sorry, it wouldn't take it all in the comment section.

Comment: @Jhorra are you sure you are on 1.10? Can you do a `var_dump(Zend_Version::VERSION);` please?

Comment: I'm giving you credit for the assist, it is some kind of setting on my test set up.  I uploaded it to the live server and it filtered just like it should.

Comment: @Jhorra do you have error_reporting(-1) enabled on your test system and ZF set to display errors? Maybe there is someone in the error logs.

Comment: I did end up using your first example for the constructor as I believe it did change in 1.10 to that format instead of what I was originally using.

Comment: @Jhorra have a look at the sourcecode for 1.10. There is a fallback in the constructor, so you can use the old instantiation as well. I have no clue why it's not working for you though.